# No torsion with calculating the commutator of the covariant derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

For simplicity, I only calculated half of the commutator. I didn't leave everything in components because I'm uncomfortable considering
(I previously messed up the indices. The following is the corrected version by Sean)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\nabla_{V^i e_i}(\nabla_{W^je_j}X^k e_k)=\nabla_{V^i e_i}(W^j (\partial_j X^k+\Gamma_{j\rho}^k X^\rho)e_k)=V^{i}{[\partial_i(W^j(\partial_j X^k+\Gamma^k_{j\rho}X^\rho)+\Gamma^k_{i\sigma}W^j(\partial_jX^\sigma+\Gamma^\sigma_{j\rho}X^\rho)]e_k}=V^i[(\partial_i W^j)(\partial_j X^k+\Gamma^{k}_{j\rho}X^\rho)+W^j\partial_i(\partial_j W^k+\Gamma^k_{j\rho}X^\rho)+\Gamma^k_{i\sigma}W^j(\partial_jX^\sigma+\Gamma^\sigma_{j\rho}X^\rho)]e_k
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(The first term in the last line should be zero, if the vector fields in nabla are simply elements of the coordinate basis $\partial_i$). But this doesn't give me the torsion term, i.e. there's no minus term that arises when you consider $\nabla_\mu X^\nu$ as a (1,1) tensor. Like here,[image: Sean Carroll]

we have $-\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda V^\rho-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\lambda \Gamma_{\lambda\sigma}^{\rho}V^{\sigma}$ in the third line.
Why would they give different result? What's wrong with my derivation.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), not images of math.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary vectors $V,W$ and $X$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\nabla_V \nabla_W X &= \nabla_{V^\lambda \partial_\lambda}(\nabla_{W^\tau \partial_\tau}X^k e_k) \\
&=\nabla_{V^\lambda \partial_\lambda}(W^\tau (\partial_\tau X^k+\Gamma_{\tau j}^k X^j)e_k) \\
&=V^\lambda[\partial_\lambda (W^\tau(\partial_\tau X^k+\Gamma^k_{\tau j}X^j))+\Gamma^k_{\lambda i}W^\tau(\partial_\tau X^i+\Gamma^i_{\tau j}X^j)]e_k \\
&=V^\lambda[ (\partial_\lambda W^\tau)(\partial_\tau X^k+\Gamma^k_{\tau j}X^j) + W^\tau \partial_\lambda (\partial_\tau X^k+\Gamma^k_{\tau j}X^j) \\
&\qquad +\Gamma^k_{\lambda i}W^\tau(\partial_\tau X^i+\Gamma^i_{\tau j}X^j)]e_k
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now if $V=\partial_\mu$, $W=\partial_\nu$, we have $V^\lambda=\delta^\lambda_\mu$, $W^\tau=\delta^\tau_\nu$.  Substituting $V^\lambda$ and $W^\tau$ into the above equation, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\nabla_{\partial_\mu} \nabla_{\partial_\nu} X &\equiv \nabla_{\delta^\lambda_\mu \partial_\lambda}(\nabla_{\delta^\tau_\nu \partial_\tau}X^k e_k) \\
&= [ \partial_\mu \partial_\nu X^k + \partial_\mu \Gamma^k_{\nu j}X^j + \Gamma^k_{\nu j}\partial_\mu X^j + \Gamma^k_{\mu i}\partial_\nu X^i + \Gamma^k_{\mu i}\Gamma^i_{\nu j}X^j]e_k.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \nabla_{\partial_\mu} \nabla_{\partial_\nu} X - \nabla_{\partial_\nu} \nabla_{\partial_\mu} X &= [\partial_\mu \partial_\nu X^k + \partial_\mu \Gamma^k_{\nu j}X^j + \Gamma^k_{\nu j}\partial_\mu X^j + \Gamma^k_{\mu i}\partial_\nu X^i + \Gamma^k_{\mu i}\Gamma^i_{\nu j}X^j]e_k \\
        &\quad - [ \partial_\nu \partial_\mu X^k + \partial_\nu \Gamma^k_{\mu j}X^j + \Gamma^k_{\mu j}\partial_\nu X^j + \Gamma^k_{\nu i}\partial_\mu X^i + \Gamma^k_{\nu i}\Gamma^i_{\mu j}X^j]e_k \\
        &= ( \partial_\mu \Gamma^k_{\nu j} - \partial_\nu \Gamma^k_{\mu j} + \Gamma^k_{\mu i}\Gamma^i_{\nu j} - \Gamma^k_{\nu i}\Gamma^i_{\mu j} ) X^j e_k \\
        &= {R^k}_{j\mu\nu} X^{j} e_k.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

$\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu X^k$ is defined as the component of the $(1,2)$-tensor:
\begin{equation}
    \nabla\nabla X = (\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu X^k) \mathrm{d}x^\mu \otimes \mathrm{d}x^\nu \otimes \partial_k.
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}
    \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu X^k - \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu X^k = {R^k}_{j\mu\nu} X^j - 2 \Gamma^\lambda_{[\mu\nu]} \nabla_\lambda X^k.
\end{equation}
But $\nabla_{\partial_\mu} \nabla_{\partial_\nu} X$ is a vector.  So $(\nabla_{\partial_\mu} \nabla_{\partial_\nu} X)^k \neq \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu X^k$.  And
\begin{equation}
    [\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu] X^k \neq ([\nabla_{\partial_\mu}, \nabla_{\partial_\nu}] X)^k.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you! But that still wouldn't give the minus terms right?

Comment: I edited my reply.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now see my problem is with the interpretation of \nabla_mu X^k is DEFINED to be a (1,1) tensor which is not at all the same thing as (\nabla_mu X)^k.

Comment: A follow up question. How does the (1,1) tensor (\nabla_mu X^nu) dx^mu \otimes \partial_nu acts on V\timesV*?

Comment: $(\nabla_\mu X^\nu) dx^\mu \otimes \partial_\nu (V,\omega) = (\nabla_\mu X^\nu) dx^\mu(V) \omega(\partial_\nu) = (\nabla_\mu X^\nu) V^\mu \omega_\nu$.

Answer (score 0):

I  prefer the notation $\nabla_X$ to the apparently more explicit  $X^\mu\nabla_\mu$ because  in the presence of torsion  there is a dangerous ambiguity lurking in the notation $\nabla_\mu$.  To see this recall that the curvature definition
$$
 [\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]Z- \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z= {\bf R}(X,Y) Z 
 $$
holds even when the connection has torsion.  Now  take $X\to \partial_\mu$ and $Y\to \partial_\nu$,  *i.e.*  $X^\lambda =\delta^\lambda_\mu$, $Y^\lambda =\delta^\lambda_\nu$ so that we are tempted to write
$$
 \nabla_{\partial_\mu}\stackrel{}{=}\delta^\lambda_\mu \nabla_\lambda\stackrel{?}{=} \nabla_\mu, \quad \nabla_{\partial_\nu}=\delta^\lambda_\nu \nabla_\lambda \stackrel{?}{=}\nabla_\nu.
 $$
Now,  remembering  that  $[\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu]=0$, our  curvature definition gives us
$$
 ([\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu] Z)^\lambda \stackrel{?}{=} Z^\alpha{R^\lambda}_{\alpha \mu\nu}. 
 $$
If, however, we include   a Christoffel  symbol ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\nu\mu}$ when  $\nabla_\mu$ acts from the left on the index $\nu$ on $\nabla_\nu$ and similarly a ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}$ when $\nabla_\nu$ is on the left and acting on the index $\mu$,  we  end up with
$$ 
( [\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu] Z)^\lambda \stackrel{?}{=} Z^\alpha{R^\lambda}_{\alpha \mu\nu}- {T^\sigma}_{\mu\nu} \nabla_\sigma Z^\lambda. 
 $$
Which is equation is correct?  With the last version, remembering that
$$
 \nabla_X Y-\nabla_Y X= [X,Y] + T(X,Y),
 $$ we can use Liebnitz rule to find
$$
( [X^\mu\nabla_\mu,Y^\nu \nabla_\nu]Z)^\lambda  = (\nabla_X Y-\nabla_YX)^\sigma \nabla_\sigma  Z^\lambda +X^\mu Y^\nu (Z^\alpha{R^\lambda}_{\alpha \mu\nu}- {T^\sigma}_{\mu\nu} \nabla_\sigma Z^\lambda)\nonumber\\
 = Z^\alpha{R^\lambda}_{\alpha \mu\nu}X^\mu Y^\nu + [X,Y]^\sigma \nabla_\sigma Z^\lambda, \nonumber
 $$
which reproduces the curvature definition for general vector fields $X$, $Y$.  Both formulae are correct in their own ways. The  difference lies  in whether we regard the $\mu$ on $\nabla_\mu$ as a shorthand  label specifying   the co-ordinate basis  vector  ${\partial}_\mu$, or as an index on the numerical  component of a covector.